# How to run a join query using an ajax request in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, laravel

I have three tables, suppose tables are tableA, tableB, tableC. Now, when I send an Ajax request to any table, I want to fetch the other two table's data by running a join query in Laravel.

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#client_id').on('change',function(){
        var id=$(this).val();
  //alert(id);
        $.ajax({
            url:"{{route('getcheque')}}",
            method:'post',
            data:{id:id,'_token':"{{csrf_token()}}"},
            success:function(response)
            {
                $('#amount_collect').val(response.cheq_amt);
            }
        });

    });
```

Request to method:

```
public function get_cheque(Request $request)
{
    $id=$request->id;
    $cdata=Directcheque::find($id);

    return $cdata;
}
```

Comment: please share your Directcheque model code

Comment: <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Directcheque extends Model
{
   
}

Comment: is your Directcheque model empty? Are you defined relationships to other tables?

Comment: no, i'm run query using DB facade.

Comment: fixed grammar and punctuation

Comment: @Majeed19 how did you defined your relationships?